# Bounded complete metric space is compact?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness

This question may seem trivial, but in topology we were taught that in a complete metric space, a subset of that space was compact if and only if it is closed and bounded. Moreover, we are told that for any topological space $X$, by definition $X$ is closed. Does it follow that if $X$ is a complete metric space, and $X$ is bounded in its metric, then $X$ is compact in that topology?

Comment: Not every closed and bounded subset of a complete metric space is compact. You have been lied to.

Comment: I doubt it because the trivial metric on an infinite space, where all distances are $1$, is bounded.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. The general characterization is that a metric space is compact if and only if it is complete and totally bounded. The latter means that for any $\varepsilon > 0$ the space has a finite cover by balls of radius at most $\varepsilon$ (this is sometimes called an "$\varepsilon$-net"). This rules out, for instance, the closed unit ball in an infinite dimensional Banach space, which is a closed, bounded, noncompact metric space.

Comment: But a totally bounded complete metric space would be compact?

Comment: @AJY Yes, that's one of the consequences of my second sentence.

Comment: Thanks. I will have to take this up with my topology teacher sometime.

Answer (score 5):

No. Consider $(\mathbb R,d)$ by the metric: $d(x,y)=\frac{|x-y|}{1+|x-y|}$.